# Stop NSString localizedStringWithFormat from putting comma

Tags: ios

NSString localizedStringWithFormat puts in comma for separating thousands.  How do you keep it from doing that. For example return 5000.25 instead of 5,000.25 (only have decimal separator)

Answer (score 3):

`localizedStringWithFormat` uses the system's locale to format the numbers. What you want is to override the default locale - use `initWithFormat:locale:` for that. Basically, it's the same function, but you also supply the locale for which to format the text.

Also, keep in mind that `initWithFormat:locale:` also retains the string (as opposed to `localizedStringWithFormat`.

Check both of them here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: can you please give an example for initWithFormat:locale:?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get the desired behavior by using NSNumberFormatter and setting its groupingSize property to 0. Then used stringFromNumber method.